# Preinstall conda envs Snakemake

Tags: python, shell, conda, snakemake, virtual-environment

When trying to run snakemake, I always have to install/download conda envs.

```
(snakemake) (ec2-user)$ bash run_snakemake.sh
Building DAG of jobs...
Creating conda environment ../envs/svg_env.yaml...
Downloading and installing remote packages.
```

Is there a way to preinstall? I notice that conda envs get installed inside `.snakemake/` folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that snakemake does not recreate the conda envs unless you delete the `.snakemake` directory or do some other tweaks. Try adding more information to your question. At the moment you are not giving any clues at what could be happening.

Comment: Generally, I don't recommend using non-Snakemake-generated Conda environments - it's just too prone to breaking reproducibility because users mutate their Conda environments. If redeploying the same pipeline, but with different inputs, then consider [containerizing the pipeline](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#containerization-of-conda-based-workflows). That way, the container is fixed and can be reused across all copies of the Snakemake workflow.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html), running this will create the envs:

```sh
snakemake --use-conda --conda-create-envs-only
```

Relevant quote:

> Conda deployment also works well for offline or air-gapped environments. Running `snakemake --use-conda --conda-create-envs-only` will only install the required conda environments without running the full workflow. Subsequent runs with `--use-conda` will make use of the local environments without requiring internet access.

Answer (score 1):

@SultanOrazbayev has the right answer for preinstall, but based on your question of reinstalling every run, I also wanted to note that by default snakemake places its `.snakemake` dir in the working directory.  If you are utilizing that to run your workflow multiple times, it could cause the environments to reinstall.  To prevent that, you can set the `singularity-prefix` and `conda-prefix` options.

Also of note, while it is called `conda-create-envs-only` it will also set up singularity images if you run with `use-singularity`.